# cron некорректно отрабатывает задачи

Tags: bash, shell, cron

ОС Debian 8.3 (jessie). Существуют две задачи для крона:

```
# cat /etc/crontab | tail -n 2

2 *     * * *   root    bash /opt/1.sh
59 23   * * *   root    bash /opt/2.sh
```

Перезапускал крон:

```
# service cron reload
[ ok ] Reloading configuration files for periodic command scheduler: cron.
# service crontab reload
crontab: unrecognized service
```

Однако первый скрипт отрабатывает каждый час (в xx:02:01), вместо выполнения каждые две минуты. Второй скрипт не отрабатывает вовсе:

```
# cat /var/log/syslog | grep ".sh" | tail -n 3
Apr  8 18:02:01 web CRON[12238]: (root) CMD (bash /opt/1.sh)
Apr  8 19:02:01 web CRON[12733]: (root) CMD (bash /opt/1.sh)
Apr  8 20:02:01 web CRON[13191]: (root) CMD (bash /opt/1.sh)
```

Оба скрипта - исполняемые:

```
# ls -l /opt/*.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 286 Apr  8 14:28 /opt/1.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 286 Apr  8 14:28 /opt/2.sh
```

Возможно что-то не работает в 2.sh, а в syslog не пишется? Содержимое 2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm ./test.csv;
wget -O ./test.csv http://www.rossvyaz.ru/opendata/7710549038-Rosnumbase/Kody_DEF-9kh.csv;
```

Файл не менялся уже несколько дней. В чем может быть причина неправильной работы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> каждый час (в xx:02:01), вместо выполнения каждые две минуты

как вы указали, так и выполяется.

для того, чтобы задание выполнялось раз в две минуты, надо написать `*/2`. см. `man 5 crontab` о подробностях.

> Второй скрипт не отрабатывает вовсе

верно. он сработает тогда, когда вы указали: в 23 часа 59 минут.

> rm ./test.csv

указывайте абсолютный путь, а не относительный. ведь в домашнем каталоге пользователя *root* у вас наверняка нет файла `test.csv`. точнее, он там **может** появиться лишь после выполнения второй из команд — `wget -O ./test.csv ...`

> Перезапускал крон

это не требуется. прямо в файле `/etc/crontab` об этом ясно и недвусмысленно написано.

Comment: большое спасибо, */2 работает каждые 2 минуты. Второй файл не выполнялся корректно из-за путаницы с путями!

Comment: /opt/2.sh запускается у вас именно в 23:59 каждый день. домашний каталог пользователя *root* находится в каталоге `/root`, если вы его не изменяли. проверить можно командой `getent passwd root` — шестое поле и будет домашним каталогом пользователя.